# How to pass a parameter to a filter method & calling the function in React onClick event with different params?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick, components

I have created a **`filter()`** method that returns an **new array if certain condition is met.**

Function to filter array:

```
filterTableData = () => {
   const userPackages: any = this.props.lenders.packages;

   const userPackageFiltered = userPackages.filter((userPackage) => {
       return userPackage.businessStatus.toLowerCase() === this.state.btnValue;
   });
   console.log(userPackageFiltered);
}
```

Then, I'm using `onClick` **React event handler** to trigger the `function`
like so:

```
<button 
    value={this.state.btnValue} 
    onClick={this.filterTableData}
>
    Invited
</button>
```

It works perfectly!

Now, I want to reuse this logic & attach it to different buttons. So, I am trying to pass **`parameters`** to my **`filterTableData()`** function like so:

```
filterTableData = (parameters) => {
   const userPackages = this.props.lenders.packages;

   const userPackageFiltered = userPackages.filter((parameters) => {
       return parameters.toLowerCase() === this.state.btnValue;
   });
   console.log(userPackageFiltered);
}
```

Then, I tried to call it like so:

```
<button 
    value={this.state.btnValue} 
    onClick={this.filterTableData(userPackage.businessStatus)}
    >
     Invited
</button>

<button 
    value={this.state.btnValue2} 
    onClick={this.filterTableData(userPackage.type)}
    >
     Draft
</button>
```

Obviously, this isn't working.

Here it is a **[sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/1eqzf84w/1/)**. I want to pass the filter value into a `parameter` to reuse this code in other buttons & filter the array with different criteria.

The behavior is similar to this **[code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/wy2rl1nyzl)**, make sure to check the "View Column" icon & the behavior of the checkboxes.

Comment: It's not clear what you intend the `parameters` argument to do. But your function doesn't actually use it, since the `parameters` variable is local to `filter`'s function argument, being a formal parameter to it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I want to use `parameters` to change the condition & therefore it returns to me a new array with different values' depending of `parameters`, but I quess I am doing it with the wrong approach

Comment: Ok, but how should the condition depend on the parameters? You'll have to give an example of input data along with the output you want for different values of `parameters`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I probably doing this wrong. But basically I'm trying to provide t the `filter()` function with different input data to evaluate it. I am trying to do this through the `onClick` event which will be called with a `parameter`. I am not claiming this is the right way. That's why I'm asking for help. How would you construct a `filter()` function that you'll utilize in many button with different evaluation results?

Comment: I have no idea how to write that function without knowing what my potential inputs look like, as well as what parameters I will accept, and how that will change the way the data is filtered. That is why I asked for this information.

Comment: Let me see if I can do a jsfiddle example. I think that will help to understand better. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199092/discussion-between-manuel-abascal-and-robin-zigmond).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aim is to filter based on the truthiness of a particular field in your data, whose name is held in the component as `this.state.buttonValue`, then you can achieve the desired effect by writing your filter method like this:

```
filterTableData(param) {
    const filteredData = this.state.data.filter(user => user[param]);
    // code to use filterdData, presumably using this.setState somewhere
}
```

And then define your `onClick` attribute as follows:

```
onClick={() => this.filterTableData(this.state.buttonValue)}
```

It's likely though that you don't just want to use the truthiness/falsiness of the values (they will likely only be falsy if they're not actually provided) - you might want an "age" filter to only select users aged over 18, for example. It's not clear what your exact needs are - but the above code should serve as a good outline, the only change will be in `filterTableData` where you may have to use a `switch` on the `param` argument and define a custom filter function for each, which you then pass in to `this.state.data.filter`. Hopefully you can work out from this what exactly you need to do for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you want to supply a custom parameter along with the `onClick` event.  To do this, you will need to use an anonymous function.

You can either use the anonymous function inline, within the `onClick` prop (FirstTest), or you can use it on the handler (SecondTest).

Please see the following example, and let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```js
const mybuttons = [{
  name: "Invited",
  value: "__some__INVITED__value__"
}, {
  name: "Draft",
  value: "__some__DRAFT__value__"
}]


function FormTest() {
  const handleClick = parameter => event => {
    switch(parameter.name){
      case "Invited": {
        alert("You clicked: INVITED! Value of: " + parameter.value);
        break;
      }
      case "Draft": {
        alert("You clicked: DRAFT! Value of: " + parameter.value);
        break;
      }
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      {mybuttons.map(button => {
        return <button onClick={handleClick(button)}>{button.name}</button>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}



/**
 * FIRST TEST
 */
function FirstTest() {
  const handleClick = parameter => {
    alert(parameter);
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("[FirstTest] My Custom Parameter 1!")}>
        First Test
      </button>  
    </div>
  );
}


/**
 * SECOND TEST
 */
function SecondTest() {
  const handleClick = parameter => clickevent => {
    alert(parameter);
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick("[SecondTest] My Custom Parameter 2!")}>
        Second Test
      </button>  
    </div>
  );
}

function App(){
  return(
    <div>
      <FormTest />
      <hr />
      <br />
      <p>Original Answer:</p>
      <FirstTest />
      <SecondTest />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's correct that I want to pass a `parameters` to the onClick event, but I also added to the `filter() ` function so evaluates different & there gives me another array. I don't know if that makes it clearer?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal yes, that makes sense - although, my example already demonstrates how to do that... I went ahead and added some additional code to my example, to try and make it a little more clear. Please check it out and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Hi Matt sorry, I just saw your reply. Thanks for your reply, however I need to pass the `parameters` to my `filter()` function in your solution, I don't find how to do that